# why node.js querysting module should convert plus (+) to space?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have noticed the below code in nodejs querystring module

```
....
var regexp = /\+/g;
....
var x = qs[i].replace(regexp, '%20'),
....
```

and if decodeURIComponet apply to %20 ,it will ouput space.
is there any special feature for + in url query?
it's confusing me a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a URI, a `+` is considered the same as a Space, which is also URI Encoded as %20.

Comment: but,if try this

    console.log(encodeURIComponent('+ ')); // %2B%20

it will output %2B

Comment: yes, %2B is how you encode a + sign, because a + sign is a special symbol in URLs that gets treated as a space or a separator.

Comment: i think i shoud read [wiki query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) carefully. thank @Jim Deville a lot.